# emberjs (unknown mixin) error when working with Ember.Object.Extend

Tags: ember.js

I'm creating an initializer in my ember app (using ember-cli 0.2.0 beta). In it, I define a user object (that I define with Ember.Object.extend) that I want to register and inject into the app's controllers.

When i print the user object (right after defining it) to the console, I’m getting “(unkown mixin)”. I've looked around but can't seem to find a solution or tell why this is the case. Here's what my initializer file looks like:

```
// app/initializers/application.js

var currentUser = Ember.Object.extend({
  authToken: localStorage['authToken'],
  isAuthenticated: function () {
    return !!this.get('authToken');
  }.property('authToken')
});

console.log(currentUser); // logs (unknown mixin)

export function initialize(container, application) {
  // register current user factory
  application.register('user:current', currentUser, {singleton: true});

  // inject factory
  application.inject('controllers', 'currentUser', 'user:current');
}

export default {
  name: 'application',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your currentUser definition/console logging into your initialize function?

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys I tried that but got the same feedback. However I found this [issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/issues/124) that seems to be related. Anyways, I was able to access the current user in my controllers, so it seems the injection worked afterall.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using `Ember.Object.create()`. What's the point of extending the  object but never creating an instance of it?

Comment: I tried that but got `Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties. Define computed properties using extend() or reopen() before calling create().` Has to do with the `isAuthenticated` property on the user.

Comment: Then try using `createWithMixins()`

Comment: Or use `.create()` after `.extend({...`

Comment: Because the Ember container handles the lifecycle of registered objects. It will call  `.create` for you as needed. The `.register` call here looks correct.